# Getting value from input box of one page and passing it to the heading of another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, textinput

I have a feature I'm struggling to implement, didn't find a proper answer anywhere.
When a user puts some text in an input form and clicks a "next" button, he sees the input text as a heading of another page.

You can login to my app to see exactly what I mean: http://murmuring-headland-8091.herokuapp.com/ 
For example, a user writes down a decision he wants to make: "Which job to choose?", and after clicking "What are your options?" button, he sees "Which job to choose?" instead of "Step 2 of 4.".

I think what I want to implement is called "a string", but I can't go any further with that knowledge.
Hope I made my question clear. I'm a newbie, so I hope to get a detailed answer.

Here's the github of my app: https://github.com/strikhar/decisions

Thank you for taking your time and helping me!

Comment: After clicking "What are your options?", it has come to "Step 2 of 4." rather than "Which job to choose?" as you reported. May be you need to check it again and then revert back.

Comment: @NeerajT That's right. It's written "Step 2 of 4.", but instead I want it to be written exactly what you put in the input form before clicking "What are your options?".

Answer (score 0):

The input field "Which job to choose?" has no name associated with it. So, you need to assign it a name for accessing the input given by user.

Once you assign it a name, say `whichjob`, you will be able to access its `string` through `params[:whichjob]`. Then using this, you can display this string in place of "Step 2 of 4."

Instead of using this means

```
<a href="/options">What are your options? -&gt;</a>
```

use a `submit` field for the same. For example,

```
<form action='/options'>
.
.
.
.
     <input type='submit' value='Submit it now and go to "What are your options?"' />
```